# Unable to compile SDL/OpenGL program under MinGW

Tags: mingw, sdl-2, mingw32

I'm having hard time making a sample SDL/OpenGL program compile for Windows (with MinGW). It compiles without error (albeit with warnings) in my virtual machine, that runs Arch. The problem seems to be at the linking stage. It dies with many "undefined reference to `symbol`" errors. I'm compiling with this command line:

```
gcc -L/mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -mwindows -I/mingw32/include/SDL2 -Dmain=SDL_main -o cube -3 cube-3.c
```

The terminal I'm running the command from is 32-bit so the libraries match the architecture type. I have checked that all libraries that are being referenced are installed in the appropriate places

```
/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libopengl32.a
/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libglu32.a
/mingw32/lib/libSDL2.a
/mingw32/lib/libSDL2main.a
/mingw32/lib/libSDL2.dll.a
```

The linker errors are all of this form:

```
C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccuBYqiv.o:cube-3.c:(.text+0x37): undefined reference to `SDL_RWFromFile
```

Unresolvable Symbols

```
SDL_RWFromFile
SDL_LoadBMP_RW
_imp__glGenTextures@8
_imp__glBindTexture@8
_imp__glTexImage2D@36
_imp__glTexParameteri@12
_imp__glTexParameteri@12
SDL_FreeSurface
SDL_Init
SDL_GetError
SDL_GL_SetAttribute
SDL_GL_SetAttribute
SDL_CreateWindow
SDL_GetError
SDL_GL_CreateContext
SDL_GetError
SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval
_imp__glEnable@4
_imp__glDepthFunc@4
glGenBuffers
glBindBuffer
glBufferData
glGenVertexArrays
glBindVertexArray
glEnableVertexAttribArray
glVertexAttribPointer
glCreateShader
glShaderSource
glCompileShader
glCreateShader
glShaderSource
glCompileShader
glCreateProgram
glAttachShader
glAttachShader
glLinkProgram
_imp__glEnable@4
_imp__glShadeModel@4
_imp__glClearColor@16
_imp__glClearDepth@8
_imp__glEnable@4
_imp__glDepthFunc@4
_imp__glHint@8
_imp__glLoadIdentity@0
_imp__glTranslatef@12
_imp__glRotatef@16
_imp__glBegin@4
_imp__glColor3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glColor3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glColor3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glColor3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glColor3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glColor3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glEnd@0
_imp__glBegin@4
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glTexCoord2f@8
_imp__glVertex3f@12
_imp__glEnd@0
_imp__glClear@4
glUseProgram
glBindVertexArray
_imp__glDrawArrays@12
SDL_DestroyWindow
SDL_Quit
SDL_StartTextInput
SDL_GetMouseState
SDL_PollEvent
SDL_GL_SwapWindow
SDL_StopTextInput
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

UPDATE --- These are the included headers in that order

```
#include <SDL.h>
 #include <SDL_opengl.h>
 #include <GL/glu.h>
 #include <GL/gl.h>

 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
```

Comment: Libraries should be specified after object files that depends on them; you set your source file in last argument while it should be somewhere among the first, and certainly before libraries. Also I don't really think you can link with "modern" GL functions like that without an extension loader, and symbol names are different for them; what header file do you use for that functions?

Comment: all right, after moving the input and the output files as the first parameters only gl- related undefined references remained

Comment: SDL_opengl.h does not define these functions. Your own code does? Anyway, it is no longer "external" symbols, so without the code it no longer makes sense to guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just as keltar points out in the comments the order of the arguments to gcc is wrong. Changing it to

```
gcc -o cube-3 cube-3.c -L/mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lglew32 -opengl32 -lglu32 -mwindows -I/mingw32/include/    SDL2 -Dmain=SDL_main
```

Note that, not only the `-o cube-3 cube-3.c` portion is shifted to the beginning, but also `lglew32` is added just before `-opengl32` (and after SDL stuff). The source file needed to refer to GL/glew.h

```
  /* Note that <GL/glew.h> is included before <GL/glu> */

 #include <GL/glew.h>
 #include <SDL.h>
 #include <SDL_opengl.h>
 #include <GL/glu.h>
 #include <GL/gl.h>

 #include <pthread.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <time.h>
```

Comment: FYI, `-o cube-3` option can be placed anywhere. It's only `cube-3.c` that had to be moved.